# Remainder Modular Arithemetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How  to solve $$11^{103} = x \bmod(143)$$ for$ x $?

I have tried using $a^{p-1}=1\pmod p$ but not really getting the idea.

Comment: Did you notice that 143 = 11 * 13  ?

Answer (score 2):

We begin by noting that $11^{102} = (13-2)^{102} = (-2)^{102} \pmod {13}$, and $(-2)^{102} = 2^{102} = (2^6)^{17} = (-1)^{17} = -1\pmod {13} = 12\pmod{13}\Rightarrow 11^{102} - 12 = 13n \Rightarrow 11^{103} - 132 = 143n \Rightarrow 11^{103}  = 132 \pmod{143}$

Comment: how come -1(mod13)=12(mod13) not clear

Comment: because $12 - (-1) = 0\pmod {13} \Rightarrow -1 = 12\pmod {13}$

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite this as $x \equiv 11^{103} \bmod(143),\,$ you can see that there is nothing to 'solve', you just compute the value $11^{103} \bmod(143)$. This can be done by any valid method (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation), here is simple one: Compute the first few powers

```
11^2 mod 143   = 121
11^3 mod 143   = 44
11^4 mod 143   = 55
11^5 mod 143   = 33
11^6 mod 143   = 77
11^7 mod 143   = 132
11^8 mod 143   = 22
11^9 mod 143   = 99
11^10 mod 143  = 88
11^11 mod 143  = 110
11^12 mod 143  = 66
11^13 mod 143  = 11
```

Note that the last result is $11.$ Therefore you compute 
$$11^{103}\equiv 11^{7\times 13 +12} \equiv 11^7\times 11^{12} \equiv 132\times 66 \equiv 132 \pmod {143}$$